# Как в slick slider задать события для прокрутки вперед и назад?

Tags: jquery, slider, события, slick.js

Всем доброго времени суток!

Делаю очередной слайдер на slick slider. Столкнулся с проблемой, нужно сделать анимацию появления слайдов при прокрутке. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как задать события для прокрутки слайдов вперед и назад?

```
if (нажали кнопку Next или прокрутили слийдер вперед) {
  alert('Слайдер прокрутился вперед');
  //Также тут должны работать события beforeChange и afterChange
}
if (нажали кнопку Previous или прокрутили слийдер назад) {
  alert('Слайдер прокрутился назад');
  //Также тут должны работать события beforeChange и afterChange
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/h7p251qp/

Comment: и чем же это отличается от `afterChange` и т.п.?

Comment: afterChange и beforeChange срабатывает при прокрутке слийдера и назад и вперед

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант использовать [jquery-mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel)

Пример

```js
var mySlider = $('.sliders');

mySlider.slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
});

mySlider.mousewheel(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
});
```

```css
.sliders {
  text-align: center;
}

.sliders>div {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.sliders>div h3 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<div class='sliders'>
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Немного не то, нужно что-бы событие срабатывало не при прокрутке колесика мышки, а при нажатии кнопок (вперед, назад) и при перетаскивании слайдов мышей или таче.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mySlider = $('.sliders');

mySlider.slick({
  dots: false,
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
});

mySlider.mousewheel(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    $(this).slick('slickNext');
  } else {
    $(this).slick('slickPrev');
  }
});
mySlider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
  if(nextSlide > currentSlide){
    alert('Вперёд')
  }else{
    alert('Назад')
  }
})
```

```css
.sliders {
  text-align: center;
}

.sliders>div {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.sliders>div h3 {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 10px;
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>

<div class='sliders'>
  <div>
    <h3>1</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>2</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>3</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>4</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>5</h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h3>6</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: То что нужно! А еще подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать тоже самое только для afterChange?

Comment: @g4343 запоминайте нужное в `before` и используйте в `after`. зы: при круговом переключении с последнего на первый код будет работать не корректно